# Remove strange files with .bat

Tags: batch

I have a lot of files like `file.epub@kifhisadfnds` and I want to delete them all using the command below, however not all are gone after using it.  Is this command correct?

```bat
FOR /R ".\MAGAZINES\" %%f IN (*.epub*) DO Del "%%f" *.epub*
```

In a second command, I want to delete all files that don't contain the words `New`, `York`, or `NYC`; How should I write that?

Comment: why not just `del *.epub@*`?

Comment: its in folder ".\MAGAZINES\"

Comment: OK, so then you `CD` into `\Magazines` and then `del *.epub@*`

Comment: OR `del .\magazines\*.epub@* /s` .. right?

Comment: What OS? Why batch & not **PowerShell**? It's more powerful & the code is easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```bat
@for /f tokens^=* %%i in('where /r "C:\full-path-to\MAGAZINES" *.epub?*
')do @echo\"%%~nxi"|findstr /i 'New  York  NYC">nul || @echo\del "%%~i"
```

If the echoed command looks good for deleting files, simply remove 2nd `echo\` command for effective execution:

```bat
@for /f tokens^=* %%i in('where /r "C:\full-path-to\MAGAZINES" *.epub?*
')do @echo\"%%~nxi"|findstr /i 'New  York  NYC">nul || @echo\del "%%~i"
```