# Searching for file in .bat

Tags: batch, batch-file, findstr

I want to delete all pdf files from a folder, that doesn't contain words 
"Times" OR "Wall" in their file names. So files 1.pdf 2.pdf All_Times_to_ride.pdf Wall.pdf are in and All_Times_to_ride.pdf Wall.pdf should be the outcome.

I have a problem with a searching script:

```
@echo off

SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET "pathToFolder=.\MAGAZINES\"
SET "wordToSearch=*Times*"
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%F IN ('dir %pathToFolder% /b *.pdf') DO (
    findstr /IP %wordToSearch% "%pathToFolder%\%%F">nul
    IF !ERRORLEVEL!==1 (
        DEL /Q "%pathToFolder%\%%F"
    )
)
```

1st. I want to search for two words in files names "Times" and "Wall"

2nd. As it is now, it deletes all files, even with All_Times_to_ride.pdf file in folder being present.

Please help, dunno how to fix it.

Comment: To clarify, you only want to delete files with both Times AND wall in the name? if so, as soon as you throw in a `*`, all bets are off.

Comment: I want to delete files WITHOUT Times or Wall word

Comment: Can you update your question then to be clearer please, specifically your expected outcome.

Comment: Sorry for my English, I want to delete all pdf files from a folder, that doesn't contain words Times OR Wall in their file names. So files 1.pdf 2.pdf All_Times_to_ride.pdf Wall.pdf are in and All_Times_to_ride.pdf Wall.pdf  should be the outcome.

Comment: **[Same author same question here](https://superuser.com/questions/1544949/remove-strange-files-with-bat/1545226#1545226)**

Comment: Read the full question, it wasn't the same.

Comment: How many accounts do you have here with different/same questions?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`FOR/F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) and [`FINDSTR`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8844868/12861751):

```
@echo off
pushd "%~dp0MAGAZINES"

FOR /F eol^=^ delims^= %%F in ('2^>nul dir /b "*.pdf"^|findstr /IV /C:"times wall"') do del /Q "%%F"

popd
```

`eol^=^ delims^=` works by escaping every [delimiter](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html#delimiters). See [How to disable both eol and delims options of for /F?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32192678/12861751)